# Design issue forcing me to down-cast base class to derived types

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I have a class accepting the base class, but it needs to accept the derived class to perform derived-class-specific operations. However I need it to be polymorphic:

```
class I{
    OL ol;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class OD{
    int data_member1;
    int data_member2;
}

class FD : public OD {
    int data_member3;
}

class ND : public OD{
    int data_member4;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OL{
    virtual void u(OD od) = 0;
}

class NL : public OL{
    //Accepts OD-type for polymorphism, but only ever uses ND-type objects
    void u(OD nd){
        //Manipulate datamember1
        //Manipulate datamember2
        //Manipulate datamember3 (which FD doesn't have)
    }
}

class CL : public OL{
    //Accepts OD-type for polymorphism, but only ever uses FD-type objects
    void u(OD fd){
        //Manipulate datamember1
        //Manipulate datamember2
        //Manipulate datamember4 (which ND doesn't have)
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have to declare the parameter type for `OL::u()` as `OD` (so that I can use polymorphism), but in `NL::u()` and `CL::u()` the parameter type must be the derived so that I can access the data members that particular derived has (`ND` doesnt have `datamember4` and `FD` doesnt have `datamember3`).

What should I do? The only solution I can think of is to down-cast the `OL` object in `NL::u()` and `CL::u()` to the derived type, but this feels very "hacky".

My overall aim is to be able to do:

```
I i1;
OD fd = new FD();
i1.ol.u(fd);

I i2;
OD nd = new ND();
i2.ol.u(nd);
```

Comment: The root of your problem is that you are abusing inheritance in your definition of NL and CL - they don't really have a common interface. But ignoring that, the Visitor pattern might help with the overrides of `u()`.

Comment: @AlanStokes they share common data members (in the actual code one of the classes has 4 data members and the other class had 6, including the former 4).

Comment: If you properly encapsulated your data members with access functions you might find it easier to define the proper interfaces for the classes.

Comment: They were omitted for simplicity. I don't see how that is relevant? Whether one of the derived classes doesn't have datamember3, or accessor function getDataMember3(), it still cannot be accessed from the parent class due to specialization, right?

Comment: Look at the Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use polymorphism and inheritence but only have data members

If your base class declares all the abstract methods then yuo could call the methods and not worry about where the data members are.

i.e. base class can contain calc(), calc() in each derived class can use whatever data members it has to create an answer

Comment: Could you relate your answer to some of my class names as I have a couple of base classes? I also don't understand your first sentence :)

Comment: Your answer sounds similar to what AlanStokes said- however I don't see how this is relevant? Whether I have accessor methods or not, I can only put accessor methods for common data members in the base class? If one of my derived classes doesn't have datamember3, then I cannot put getDataMember3() in the base class?

Comment: @user997112 - you are trying to do x -- in order to x you need dataum a1 and a2 -- you are looking and saying i need data a2, so i have to down cast -- instead just create x and have it use a2 where it is needed